# NSMutable Array in iOs 5

Tags: ios5, nsmutablearray

I am creating one application in iOs 5 using story board and in that application I need to use  one NSMutableArray for table View.
so I am creating that array as shown below.
but in iOs 4 we creating array like

```
@interface MySpots : UITableViewController{
       NSMutableArray *MySpots;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *MySpots;
```

and in .m file

```
@synthesize MySpots;
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
     [super viewDidLoad];
      MySpots = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
          mySpot.SpotName = @"Name Of Spot";
          mySpot.SpotTime = @"15mi";
          mySpot.SpotDis = @"Short preview of the description will appear in this section.Acts as a reminder for relevant";
          [MySpots addObject:mySpot];
       }

}
```

but when i try to do this in iOs 5 it will show me error("Expected identifier or {" ) on

```
MySpots = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

because in iOs 5 no need to release. so how should i have to declare NSMutableArray in iOs 5 .
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with iOS 5 but rather is a compiler error from objective C. The basic problem is that you use `MySpots` both as interface name and as property/instance variable. When encountering your line

```
MySpots = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

the compiler now is unsure if this is the variable `MySpots` or should be a declaration of a variable of type `MySpots`, e.g.

```
MySpots *mySecondController = ...;
```

The compiler assumes the second and bails out because of the missing variable name.

You should

1. change that property's name to something different than the class name to avoid confusion
2. use `self.property =` instead of `property =` because this uses the correct memory management. ARC somewhat reduces this problem but it is good practice anyway to use the automatic retain/release provided by properties.

Either one of those would help (in case 1 the compiler now is clear on what to do, in case 2 `self.MySpots` would be a unique name and could not be mixed up with the class name) but I would definitely do both, rename the property (or class) and use `self.property =`.

PS: Even with ARC you still initialize as usual by using `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` ARC just inserts the appropriate `retain` and `releases` behind the scenes.

Comment: ya,its working i changed name of property and it will works,thanks TriPhoenix

Answer (score 0):

That exact code can never ever have compiled, let alone worked correctly!

First of all: where does the local variable `mySpot` you are using in your loop come from in the first place?

Second, I am pretty much positively sure that you **cannot** name a variable **identical** to a type: `MySpots` is both a class and an ivar of that same class? 
If that declaration worked on some weird compiler, I would consider that a bug in the compiler. And even *if* that declaration compiled — that's an awful lot of ifs, already — the line where you use that variable **cannot** work, because the compiler cannot know whether you meant the type `MySpots` or the instance variable — the weird thing that compiled thus far *may* do something here but I would not put any trust in the validity of the code output of such a "compiler".

And that's where your error message comes from.